# Homebrew failing to install - fatal: not in a git directory

Tags: bash, git, error-handling, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install homebrew on a macOS and I'm failing with the following message:

```
h
==> Installation successful!



==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.

Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:

  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics

No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).



==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:

  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations



fatal: not in a git directory

Failed during: git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true
```

Any ideas of what it could be and how to fix it? Many thanks (:

Comment: This questions was really helpful in finding the answer. I don't know why people upvote answers more than questions! At the very least they should upvote both.

Answer (score 19):

Reinstalling homebrew, solves the problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew
```

to remove everything before you landed here ;) and then run

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please explain in few words what this is doing? (i reckon its like a re-install)

Comment: It indeed is a reinstall @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3148807/sagiv-b-g

Comment: It's something homebrew error. This solution helped me. Thanks, man...

Comment: Just wanted to note that it seems like now homebrew is installed into `/opt`, so the first command should be
```sudo rm -rf /opt/Homebrew```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. runs this command:

   `unset HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE`
2. Run the curl command again:

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 2):

Can you run the following commands to see if it helps?

```
$ cd `brew --prefix`
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

Also it would be helpful if you can attach `brew doctor` and `brew config` in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @chenrui, are you sure that it is necessary to `go brew --prefix`, no need to enter to Homebrew folder then?
I have error: 
$ cd `brew --prefix`
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
(base)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, running this command; "/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

I got this log; 
=> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
/usr/local/homebrew/.git: Permission denied

I gave permission to /user/local/homebrew and now I can test with brew....

Comment: It's better to answer the question directly here, rather than link out to an article. From the SO guidelines: "Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself."